# How to Call Function on Each dom-repeat Element

Tags: polymer-2.x, dom-repeat

I am trying to call a function on each element inside of a `dom-repeat` template.

```
<dom-repeat items="[[cart]]" as="entry">
  <template>
    <shop-cart-item id="item"></shop-cart-item>
  </template>
</dom-repeat>
```

...

```
checkStatus() {
  this.$.item.doSomething();
}
```

**How can I call `doSomething` on each element?**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can iterate through nodes like:

```
checkStatus() {
  const forEach = f => x => Array.prototype.forEach.call(x, f);

  forEach((item) => {
    if(item.id == 'cartItem') {
      console.log(item);
      item.doSomething(); // call function on item
    }
  })(this.$.cartItems.childNodes)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add an `on-tap` event in the loop. In order to observe which item you clicked look into `model` property :

```
<dom-repeat items="[[cart]]" as="entry">
  <template>
     <!-- need to give dynamic id for each item in dome-repeat -->
    <shop-cart-item id="[[index]]" on-tap = 'checkStatus'></shop-cart-item>

  </template>
</dom-repeat>
```

...

```
checkStatus(status) {
  console.log(status.model)  // you can get index number or entry's properties.
  this.$.item.doSomething();
}
```

**EDIT:**

So as per comment of @Matthew, if need to call a function in one of element's function in `dom-repeat` first give a dynamic `id name` as above then:

```
checkStatus(status) {
  this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#'+ status.model.index).doSomething();
}
```